# How to create the fuel models & live fuel moisture rasters for Wildfire simulation?

Tags: grass-gis, simulation

Has anybody done wildfire modelling in GRASS?  Where could I obtain / how do I create the fuel models and live fuel moisture rasters to determine rate of spread (r.ros)?

Comment: Have you tried [WFAS](http://www.wfas.net)?

Comment: You may want to check with the "Fire simulation data" set from http://grass.osgeo.org/download/sample-data/

Comment: Bernie, some (wildland fire) fuel models are a classification of the vegetation based on the _type_ and the _density_ of the vegetation. For example, I have in mind major forest type classes (Deciduous or Evergreen  and  Broadleaved or Coniferous and Mixed as well -- set aside lower vegetations such as shrubs, scrubs or grasses). Then density classes, i.e. Sparse, Open, Dense. If you get all of these and mix'em together, you are, in theory, producing a kind of a (forest) fuel map.

Comment: Thanks Nikos :)  I've figured it all out, except I somehow need to adapt the American fuel models to South African vegetation. Finding appropriate landcover data at a high enough resolution is also a bit of a challenge.

Comment: What's the spatial resolution you are after?

Comment: At this stage, I guess anything would be better than that which I have access to!  Whatever I've found so far is very generic and doesn't take different types of vegetation into account i.e. it may only provide the biome type which then does not include plantations or farm orchards or areas where an abundance of alien invasive species are found. These all of course have a major influence on fires.

Comment: There is also a wiki page showing the basic concept of [creating inputs for r.ros](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/How_to_create_parameters_to_run_r.ros).

Comment: Thanks, I've had some time to work on fire risk analysis in my spare time and have figured most of it out.  Now just to test whether my methodology is correct.

Comment: Congratulations, if you have something at least partially general from your workflow, please feel free to share it, e.g. at the GRASS wiki page http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/How_to_create_parameters_to_run_r.ros.